# Связь двух программ через интернет

Tags: delphi, сеть

Здравствуйте, каким способом можно соединить две программы сделанных на Delphi( допустим для передачи текста)

> через интернет

. 
Сокет - не решение, он только в локальной сети работает, может вы знаете какие-нибудь компоненты ?

Я делал так:

1. Программа-сервер загружает текстовый файл на сервер(бесплатный хостинг)
2. Программа-клиент проверяет наличие файлов, и если они есть - качает, а затем удаляет с сервера.

Вроде бы и большего не нужно, но методика ужасная.
Возможно,вы,знаете какие-нибудь компоненты для такого дела?
(через интернет, а то советую сокеты, но они же только по локальной сети...)
Спасибо.

Comment: Сокет - не решение, он только в локальной сети работает, может вы знаете какие-нибудь компоненты ?

Почему то у меня особых проблем с сокетом нет более двух лет на Delphi 7, а, с недавнего времени, и на XE4.На уровне Delphi абсолютно безразлично локальная сеть или i-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я работаю только с бинарной информацией,поэтому использую TClientSocket и, соответственно, TServertSocket. Для текста возможностей больше. Локальная или интернет - вопрос только в быстродействии.

Comment: А возможно ли стандартными инструментами компоненты TServerSocket реализовать связь? ну через интернет (разные провайдеры и города)?

Comment: (разные провайдеры и города)?

От этого зависят только надежность (устойчивость) связи и быстродействие. У меня, в частности, сервер - GPRS модем на базе SIM900 (мобильный провайдер). Соединяюсь с ним и в Беларуси и РФ.
Т.е., повторяю,Локальная или интернет - вопрос только в быстродействии (и надежности).

Comment: Просто я уже организовал подключение клиента и сервера, всё ок, но только на локальном компьютере, выхожу дальше - на ноутбук и ПК и уже связи нет. по ошибке я читал что это из-за: 

1)Стоит фаервал (а его нету,я всё что мог - закрыл) 
2)Внешний IP, но и айпи менял, допустит тот который внешний(из сайта определил) тоже не находит клиент - сервер.

В настройках сервера я задавал только айпи и порт, возможно я что-то да и не включил?

Comment: Юрий, проблема может быть в следующем:
подключении к i-net провайдер произвольно назначает IP. Решается все просто. За небольшую плату провайдер присваивает статический (фиксированный)адрес. По крайней мере такая услуга имеется у всех известных мне провайдеров (Беларусь,РФ,Украина).
Если проблем в локальной сети нет, то не должно быть и в i-net.

Comment: То есть, я всё сделал правильно (кроме айпи и порта ничего не нужно?)
. Если да, то значит проблема в провайдере, или порт может быть роутер закрыть?

Comment: ДА!!!!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется Вам стоит рассмотреть написание плагина под какой-либо из существующих IM-менеджеров. Этот плагин должен быть связанным с Вашей программой и посредством API предоставляемого самим менеджером можно будет организовать двустороннее общение. К примеру Miranda обладает многими протоколами и написав для нее плагин Вы можете встать и на несколько уровней выше поверх каких-либо сетей и поверх всех этих протоколов. Признаю что мысль "попахивает", но все же имеет право на жизнь ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Сокет - не решение, он только в локальной сети работает

Вызывающе неверная информация. Сокеты - это не более (но и не менее) чем надстройка над протоколом TCP, на котором работает большинство интернет-сервисов. Если у Вас сокеты не заработали с интернет-адресами - ищите проблему в настройках.

Ну а вообще представленной информации маловато, чтобы категорически давать направление движения. В некоторых (не очень, правда, частых) случаях UDP предпочтительнее TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Через сокет всё работает. Если для передачи текста попробуйте UDP на IdUDPServer и IdUDPClient.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdUDPClient1.Send(Edit2.Text+'  '+Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
StringFormatedStream : TStringStream;
s: String;
begin
//Инициализация
StringFormatedStream := TStringStream.Create('');
//Копирование из простого потока в строковый
StringFormatedStream.CopyFrom(AData, AData.Size);
//Вывод полученного сообщения
Memo1.Lines.Add(ABinding.PeerIP+' '+StringFormatedStream.DataString);
//Перенаправление сообщения дальше
ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, s [1], Length(s));
//Освобождение строкового потока
StringFormatedStream.Free;
end;
```

Указав IP адреса и порты всё получится.